# Zimbra server status showing red in control panel

Tags: debian-lenny, zimbra

I have been having a weird problem with Zimbra(7.1.4_GA_2555.DEBIAN5) lately:

On the (web)control panel the status keep changing to red every few days. When this is happens the output of zmcontrol status still shows running:

```
antispam                Running
antivirus               Running
imapproxy               Running
ldap                    Running
logger                  Running
mailbox                 Running
memcached               Running
mta                     Running
snmp                    Running
spell                   Running
stats                   Running
zmconfigd               Running
```

Every thing runs fine except automated mail forwarding from one account to another(which is critical for us).

I have been through Zimbra forums and the following ALWAYS fixes the issue:

```
su - zimbra -c "zmprov mcf zimbraLogHostname mail.mydomain.com"
/opt/zimbra/libexec/zmsyslogsetup
/etc/init.d/rsyslog restart
su - zimbra -c "zmcontrol restart"
```

After I run the above commands, the status on control panel turns green and mail forwarding starts to work again BUT only for a few days.

Other than the above, everything works fine including Server statistics.

Anyone seen this issue before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue after going through the following link:

http://www.zimbra.com/forums/installation/34359-upgrade-6-0-2-stats-status-no-longer-working-6.html

since my system is using rsyslog instead of standard syslog it will never reload the syslog-deamon and therefore you have problems with the logfiles. This is even more problematic as zimbra begins with z and therefore it is the last script which gets executed from logrotate, if it would not be the last one, there would have been a chance that a later script reloads the syslog daemon :-) I changed this line to:

killall -HUP rsyslogd 2> /dev/null || true

(notice the r in front of rsyslogd)